# Filter results from RegEx pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I started working on a Chrome extension that puts links on certain expressions when the user visits a webpage. This is the code I've been using so far.

```
var input = document.body.innerHTML;
var pattern = /(?!<a[^>]*?>)(\s|>)(\.(gitignore|travis\.yml)|package\.json)(?![^<]*?<\/a>)\b/gm;
 document.body.innerHTML  = input.replace(pattern,"$1<a href='$2.html'>$2</a>");
```

The linked files are part of a documentation project I'm working on. Since I want to avoid working with hidden files (e.g. `.gitignore.html`), I would love to filter the dot in `$2` for the actual links, but keep the full expression in the link text.

The result should look like this:

```
<a href="gitignore.html">.gitignore</a>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand. Do you want to append `.html` to the hidden files and remove the dot in the beginning ? Also, can you provide a `text` snippet?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Also the code in question is **incomplete**, add some description of what is not working and what is expected behaviour. Also, if possible create live demo.

Comment: Rephrased the question and updated the example

Comment: Check [`$1<a href='$3.html'>$2</a>`](https://regex101.com/r/oP0bT9/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could come up with the following regular expression:

```
var input = document.body.innerHTML;
var regex = /<a\s+(?!href=\"(?:gitignore|htaccess|htpasswd)\.html\")[^>]*?>(?:\.(gitignore|htpasswd|htaccess))<\/a>/gm;
var output = input.replace(regex,"<a href='$1.html'>.$1</a>");
```

See a working demo here: https://regex101.com/r/aT7tA3/2

**Hints**:

It does not preserve any classes, attributes, rels whatsoever. If you'll need these, consider using a parser or a decent JS library (e.g. jQuery) instead.

Comment: Great, thank you. Tried something similar, but got the brackets wrong :)

Comment: @idleberg Glad it helped.

Comment: Actually, the part looking for the anchor part is wrong. Since I only want to put links on a string, if it hasn't been linked already!

Comment: @idleberg See the updated answer, I have added a negative lookahead, though this can possibly be optimized with a backreference.